# Bootstrap 5 modal JavaScript event listener

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, addeventlistener, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap v5.1.3 with vanilla JavaScript but must have misunderstood how to set up modal event listeners. This is how I have set up them up for two modals:

```
var firstModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("firstModal"));
var firstModalEL = document.getElementById('firstModal');

firstModalEL.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    console.log("firstModal");

});
 
var secondModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("secondModal"));
var secondModalEL = document.getElementById('secondModal');

secondModalEL.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

   console.log("secondModal");

});
```

But when the second modal is shown using

```
secondModal.show();
```

the event listener for the first one executes.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: It seems fine to me. Could you share the full runnable code? I can help you to look into it.

Comment: Hi Nick, that's very kind of you but I'd have to get permission first. I'll just have to man up and seek out the bug but if I don't make any headway then I'll take you up on your offer.

Comment: sure! ping me once you need my help

Comment: Like all the best bugs it wasn't in the JS; the second modal was missing a close div for the modal body and that threw everything out. Many thanks for your offer of help though.

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

While the bug in question has been found (see the comments to the original post), I'd like to add a demo of setting up multi-modals.  Here is a complete HTML code for two listeners with two modals.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Modal</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Modal Events</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal-1">
  Launch demo modal 1
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal-2">
  Launch demo modal 2
</button>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-1" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
                 Modal Test 1
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-2" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
                 Modal Test 2
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
const modal1   =document.getElementById('myModal-1');
modal1.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function(event) { console.log("show.bs.modal event 1") });

const modal2  =document.getElementById('myModal-2');
modal2.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function(event) { console.log("show.bs.modal event 2") })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added a few words for the explanation. Please let me know if anything else is needed to lead to the demo code.